# External Style Sheet partly not working

Tags: css

I made an external style sheet, uploaded it to godaddy, and gave my main page the link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">
```

and it worked, but not on Firefox (it did work on all other browsers I tried). Then I tried to link my other pages to the style sheet and it did not work for them (copied and pasted the link tag above, but when that didn't work I tried doing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public_html/myStyle.css">
```

which is the full file directory to the style sheet, and that didn't work either. Note: When I just opened the other pages on a browser, (without uploading to godaddy) the external style sheet worked in all of my pages.
This is the first time I'm trying this, so might be making an obvious mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't mix between the server filesystem and relative links, the client don't have access to the directories on the server

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm sort of new to this

Comment: First of all, why didn't it worked on FF? Did you see any errors in the console/network tabs?

Comment: that means where your files are located on your computer and godaddy is not necessarily the same...just mind where you upload your HTML and CSS files and everything should be ok.  Both your HTML and CSS should be in the public_html directory...

Comment: Nope, it just reverted to an earlier version of the site, whereas when I look it up on other browsers it shows the latest version.

Comment: Maybe it's just a caching problem. Try doing a "hard refresh" (I think that how it's called) - Refresh the page using `Ctrl + F5` OR `Ctrl + Shift + R`

Comment: My HTML and CSS are both in public_html, but the other pages (besides the main one) are in different subfolders. Do I need to have all the files in the same subfolder?

Comment: Thanks! The hard refresh worked for that problem

Comment: No all the files do not need to be in the same subfolder, but when you try to link to your CSS make sure the path is correct - to go up a directory do ../, for example

Comment: Thanks everyone. Fixed it by adding a slash to the file name (/myStyle.css)